# Are shared libraries with AMD a good idea?

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm fairly new to JS development and trying to figure out some best practices for developing and using AMD libraries. Suppose I'm developing a javascript library which depends on jquery, underscore, and whatever else. Furthermore I want to make this library an AMD module and optimize it into a big monolithic file. But the question is, how monolithic? Should it also pull in jquery and underscore so that it's completely self-contained? It seems like the pros and cons of this approach are:

#### Pro: it's easy to use

- as an app developer using this library you can just get it and add a dependency on it, without needing to know that you need jquery, underscore, etc
- no having to configure requirejs with the paths to those things
- no worrying about the case where one library needs jquery 1.x while another library needs 2.x

#### Con: it's bloated

- if the main application or another library also needs to use jquery, which seems likely, it will essentially get downloaded twice (or n times)

Anything I'm missing here? So which is the right way to do this, or is the answer "it depends", or "make versions of both"? It seems like in general you'd like to share code where possible, but it puts the onus on the consumer of libraries which have non-included dependencies, and necessitates a tool which solves the constraints to find a version of a given library which is compatible with all dependent components. Is there something out there that does something like this?

Comment: _"Should it also pull in jquery and underscore[...]"_ -- I would say **no**, that's why AMD exists in the first place, so I'd say that's the right way.

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of any good reason to include a third party library (such as jQuery or Underscore) with your own library. It's rare to see this technique employed anywhere, if at all, as it restricts the consumer of your code too much.

Not only would it add bloat as you say, but what if I wanted to use Zepto or Lo Dash, or a different version of jQuery? If your library simply lists jQuery and Underscore as a dependency then I could easily map those to load alternate versions or libraries.

Users of AMD (and RequireJS) are typically very comfortable with configuring paths, maps and shims as it necessary in nearly all instances, so I wouldn't worry about that.

Keeping everything separate will also allow flexibility when it comes to optimising the JS for production. For example, I often like the build jQuery into a `main` module that is loaded on all pages and set other modules to exclude it.

An example of what I mean with that can be seen here:
https://github.com/simonsmith/modular-html-requirejs

Answer (score 0):

I would say you should provide an unoptimized version and an optimized one. If for some reason you can't do both then just provide the unoptimized version. Why the unoptimized version?

- Your code is probably not bug-free. It is easier for someone using your library to track down a bug and maybe contribute a patch if there is a 1-for-1 mapping between the original source and what they observed in their debugging environment. (I've tried source maps. They *were* useful but produced funky results.)
- You've said it yourself: libraries like jQuery could end up being loaded n times in the final application. If you provide a way to let the developers use just your library, they can run tests to determine whether they can replace different versions of jquery with just one. (The majority of cases where a library mentions or ships a specific version of jQuery, it's just because it happened to be the version that was current when the library was made, and not because of a hard dependency.)

Provide the optimized version so that someone who just wants to try our library can do it fast.

You ask:

> It seems like in general you'd like to share code where possible, but it puts the onus on the consumer of libraries which have non-included dependencies, and necessitates a tool which solves the constraints to find a version of a given library which is compatible with all dependent components. Is there something out there that does something like this?

Yes. A test suite. As a consumer of libraries, I'm unlikely to use one that does not have a substantial test suite. As a producer of software, I don't produce software without a substantial test suite. As I've said above, most often a library that depends on something like jQuery or underscore or what-have-you will list whatever version that happened to be around when the library was developed.